# I need to ask him whether he has done any grave mistakes in his last birth

Tags: sentence-construction, present-perfect

> I need to ask him whether he **has done** any grave mistakes in his last birth.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? I am confused whether to use 'had done' or 'has done'.

Comment: On a side note, when the time phrase (here, "his last birth") refers to a past time and excludes the present, the present perfect is not idiomatic. Instead you should use a past tense (**made any mistakes** or **had made**) not the present perfect (**has made...**).

Comment: Since you used *last birth*, are you referring to rebirth cycles? And if so, is it asking about the current lifetime or the previous one? But if you mean just in this lifetime, don't use *last*.

Answer (score 2):

In English you don't "***do*** mistakes", you "***make*** mistakes". The past tense of "*make*" is "*made*". So you say "***made*** mistakes" if you are talking about something that happened in the past.

As far as your example, the correct way of saying this would be:

> I need to ask whether he **made any grave mistakes** during his last
>   birth.

(Note that I also replaced "*in his last birth*" with "*during his last birth*", which sounds a bit more natural to me)